# Scheme function: calculating distance of 2 "vectors" of any size

Tags: scheme

My vectors are defined as:

```
(x1, x2, …, xn) and (y1, y2, …yn)
```

I'm trying to calculate them like so:

```
sqrt((x1-y1)*(x1-y1) + (x2-y2)*(x2-y2) + … + (xn-yn)*(xn-yn))
```

I'm having trouble with vectors of more than 2 elements. I've been trying to use a for-each loop but I can't get the recursion to work right.

Also, I can get everything but the sqrt of the final number. I tried to define the final number as a variable, then take the sqrt of that variable, but my interpreter said something about "define not allowed in expression . . .".

My working code so far:

```
(define vectordistance 
  (lambda (v1 v2)
  (if 
   (null? v1) 0
      (+ 
      (*
      (- (car v1) (car v2))
      (- (car v1) (car v2))
      ) 
      (vectordistance (cdr v1) (cdr v2))
      )
  )
))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you're using *lists* - a `vector` is a different beast in Scheme. The key point for the solution is that you have to *iterate* over the lists, and somehow accumulate the answer until there are no more elements left. Also, a helper function will be useful here, because first we have to accumulate the addition and take the square root only at the end. Assuming that both lists have the same length:

```
; this is the same as yours, but better formatted
(define (helper v1 v2)
  (if (null? v1)
      0
      (+ (* (- (car v1) (car v2))
            (- (car v1) (car v2)))
         (helper (cdr v1) (cdr v2)))))

; call the above as a helper and take the square root of the result    
(define (vectordistance v1 v2)
  (sqrt (helper v1 v2)))
```

As a bonus (suggested by Chris) you can write the `helper` in a more idiomatic way by using a `fold` procedure. Check your interpreter's documentation, it might be called `foldl` or `fold-left` or simply `fold`, but this is how you'd use it - the idea is to avoid using explicit recursion and favoring the use of higher-order procedures:

```
(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(define (helper v1 v2)
  (foldl (lambda (e1 e2 r)
           (+ (square (- e1 e2)) r))
         0
         v1 v2))
```

Comment: thanks Oscar. you keep saving my life. appreciate it. i had no idea Scheme had vectors. i thought lists were the only containers Scheme had. i think my original code worked for more than 2 elements (minus the sqrt), i just assumed it didnt cause this recursion stuff has my brain warped haha.

Comment: I am itching so much to change that into a `fold`, you have no idea. `(fold (lambda (e1 e2 r) (+ (square (- e1 e2)) r)) v1 v2)` or something similar (not tested). ;-) But I understand you were trying to preserve the OP's code as much as possible....

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young you got it ;)